# Show badge on Questions/Answers that generated a badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-interface

I know that you could know that a Question/Answer achieved certain badge just by knowing the rules and knowing that if it has X number of votes it got Y badge, but I think it would be nice if we could see a little badge/trophy icon somewhere in the post, maybe under Favorite Star or to the right of the question title or somewhere you think its a good fit.

I think it would be a nice way for people to see that the question had some recognition for its value, and maybe even motivate people to want to have them in their questions.

I think it would also add an extra value for questions that users want to show off in Careers 2.0, since employers may not be familiar with how the system works or how many votes questions usually get, but having a little trophy icon will show that it was indeed a good answer.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty decent idea. However, I'd limited this to batches that can be achieved through this question/answer only (like Great Answer), and not show batches where this question/answer triggered a batch that required a certain amount of activities (like Generalist or Mortaboard).

Comment: Yes I agree, it should be for posts that generated the badge by themselves

Comment: @sbi: I think you meant "badges", not "batches". (Both are words, but they mean very different things.)

Comment: @Marti: Yes, I do. I keep doing this wrong. Sorry. I'm just a furr'ner.

Comment: Can we display the badges in the [Mortal Kombat font](http://www.fonts4free.net/custom.php?owntext=Reversal!&ttf=mk5style.ttf)?

Comment: @jwiscarson: [Like this](http://www.fonts4free.net/custom.php?owntext=Nice%20Answer!&ttf=mk5style.ttf)?

Comment: @Rocket, you nailed it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if I support it yet, because, as @jzd says, it will create quite a clutter:

[image]

---

We can also use this compact version, but I think that it lose all meaning:

[image]

Comment: nice workup!

Comment: Thanks, @jzd. All work done with MS Paint, MS Snipping Tool and MS mouse.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this adds much value so I am opposed to it.  The main badges you get for a specific question are related directly to views or votes.  Both of which are prominent on the page and possibly obvious from the link that brought the user to the question.  The career's argument might be more acceptable, but I don't think it is worth the clutter on the normal question pages.

Answer (score 5):

I found this question when searching to see if someone else asked it. I think this is a great way to draw attention to the badge system and to teach people the rules. Yes, some questions earn multiple badges, but others do not -- especially on sites other than SO where all the numbers run a little lower.

I think it's nice to see that a question is a Famous Question or an answer was a Guru answer, even though there is (in some cases pretty small-print) other information on the page from which you would deduce it. I would suggest, in fact, that the only badges to list would be those where all the info is on the page: Enlightened, Good, Great, Guru, Nice, Populist, Reversal, and Revival for answers and Famous, Favorite, Good, Great, Nice, Notable, Popular, Stellar, and Tumbleweed for Questions. Since we can click the badge to see what question we got it for, it follows that the question can show what was got for it. If we could also show Announcer, Booster, and Publicist that would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at this feature in the eyes of the average visitor. The information displayed on the page and especially in the question and its answers should all be relevant to the visitors. Simply put, **the average visitor couldn't care less about what badges it's received**. It's not at all useful information, and would only serve to distract visitors from looking at the content they *came here for*.

There's absolutely no benefit to displaying such information other than satisfying people's curiosity, so there's no point in displaying it.

Comment: In addition, almost all badge information is already there, just in a form of numbers (upvotes, favourites, views, and bounty if exists). The only one which is not obvious for questions is Tumbleweed... For answers, it is a bit trickier.

Comment: I guess you could say the same for the gold/silver/bronce medal count that is shown besides everybodies pictures in their answers. Why do we put them? Well to let other people know that they are indeed valuable/knowledgeable members. For questions / answers it could let people know that that specific question/answer has certain merit/ is or particular interest.

Comment: @bangoker That can already be shown by information that's already visible and actually *has* meaning. Showing an icon to represent "this question got 10 upvotes" is pretty useless and a *complete* waste when one could just look at the question's score and see the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I think about having it on the post page. I'd have to think about that more.

I do think having some way of showing off certain badges earned with particular questions/answers is interesting. Though I think it might be better suited for your profile. This is something we are exploring. The exact implementation is still being determined, but we're definitely investigating it.